# Fixing ManagementForm-data

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, formset

I have some code which looks like this:

```
<table>
    {% for n in model %}
        {% for i in formset.forms %}
            {% if forloop.parentloop.counter == forloop.counter %}
                <tr>
                <th>{{ n }}</th>
                {% for j in i %}
                    <th>{{ j }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I really want to keep it this way, because this is the presentation I've been asked for. However, I keep getting the "ManagementForm-data missing or tampered with" error, obviously because I'm messing with the formset.

Is there a smart way to fix the managementform-data so my POST will go through, or do I have to reformat my template completely?

(Yes, I am aware that my code contains an ugly, inefficient hack. Please feel free to suggest an alternative, but performance doesn't matter.)

Comment: This does not only is very inelegant. It will scale quadratic in time complexity. As a result from the moment this contains 100+ forms, it will take ages to render this. Furthermore it does things in the template language that should be done in the view. The template language of Django *deliberately* is restricted to avoid to do things like that.

Comment: I am aware of this. It doesn't matter. This form never renders more than 20 objects. Ever. And it never will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error about missing management form data because you haven't included the management form with `{{ formset.management_form }}`. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates) for more info.

To prevent the double loop in the template, you can zip `model` and `formset.forms` in the view:

```
models_and_forms = zip(model, formset.forms)
```

Then loop through the `models_and_forms` in the template:

```
<table>
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for n, i in models_and_forms %}
        <tr>
            <th>{{ n }}</th>
            {% for j in i %}
                <th>{{ j }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Great answer Alasdair, thanks. I think I got caught up in trying to fix everything in the template.